# How can I generated the function call graph (with API calls) of a .NET executable?

Tags: ida, .net, c#, dnspy, call-graph

For native executables, I can use IDA to generate the function call graph (FCG) of that executable (which includes API calls as well, for example function sub_xxx has an arrow to CreateFile which means it calls that API).

But FCG generation of IDA doesn't doesn't generate a useful FCG with .NET executables (at least the FCG that I am looking for).

My question is, is there any tool that can analyze and generate a FCG for a .NET executable? I want this FCG to include API calls as well, so function x of class y will be a node, and if that function calls something like WriteConsole, I want that node to connect to WriteConsole API node (preferably with a distinctive coloring).

Basically I want to generate something similar to the following, but for .NET executables:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: @EmreEkmekcioglu Nope :(